# Criar array dentro do objeto JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Eu estou criando um array em JSON, e gostaria de saber como faço para criar outro array dentro do objeto.

```
var objeto;
objeto = {
    "item" : [
     {
        "id" : delDiv,
        "nome" : nomeItem.value,
        "cod" : codItem.value
      }
     ]
}
```

Eu gostaria de criar um novo item, com novas informações sem sobrescrever as informações já colocadas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize o [array push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) para adicionar um novo item dentro desse atributo, segue um exemplo:

```
var novo_item = {
    "id" : delDiv2,
    "nome" : nomeItem2.value,
    "cod" : codItem2.value
};

objeto.item.push(novo_item);
```

ou

```
objeto.item.push({
    "id" : delDiv2,
    "nome" : nomeItem2.value,
    "cod" : codItem2.value
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Já tentaste, por exemplo, isso:

```
       objeto = {
            "item" : [
                {
                    "id" : delDiv,
                    "nome" : nomeItem.value,
                    "cod" : codItem.value
                },
                {
                    "id" : delDiv2,
                    "nome" : nomeItem2.value,
                    "cod" : codItem2.value
                },
                {
                    "id" : delDiv3,
                    "nome" : nomeItem3.value,
                    "cod" : codItem3.value
                }
            ],
            "array2" : [
               //objetos do outro array
            ]
       }
```

Se quiseres fazer um loop e inserir vários "itens" no array `item`, tu podes `objeto.item.push(novo_item);` onde `novo_item` é o objeto a ser inserido no array.

Comment: Pensei nisso, mas esse código está dentro de uma function, e eu queria que cada vez que essa função fosse executada, adicionasse mais um item.

Comment: Usa [array push](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)